# Get subcollection data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This my first time using firestore so I'm trying to get the data of a subcollection:

Here's my data structure

[image]

[image]

My code for that:

```
db.collection("pointage").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    console.log(1);
    querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
        console.log(2);
        document.ref.collection("listStudents").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            console.log(3);
            querySnapshot.forEach((result) => {
                console.log(4);
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

But always stuck after display the console.log(1);

Comment: At first glance the code looks fine. What does "stuck" mean? Also: can you add a `catch` to the `get` calls? This allows you to see if you have any authorization problems, which would be my first guess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the catch for each function (I updated my question) but nothing to show, and I mean by stuck that the others number (2, 3, 4) not displayed on the console.

Comment: Hmm... if you only get `1` it means that you are getting an empty result from the `pointage` collection. Can you reproduce this in a site like jsbin/jsfiddle/stackblitz, so that I can have a look?

Comment: This is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/amineharbaoui/nn1v8c9d/3/

Comment: `console.log(querySnapshot.size);` shows `0`, which indicates that there are no results for the query. Are you sure you're looking at the same project? Also: double check for spelling/spaces around your collection name.

Comment: Same for `db.doc("pointage/31_05_2018_(11:33)").get().then((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.exists);
      });`, which says that the document doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm sure that I'm using the correct project, also I checked the collections names there is nothing wrong. really this is weird

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what's going on. Hopefully someone else here sees it. In the meantime: can you read from the other collections?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172256/discussion-between-amine-harbaoui-and-frank-van-puffelen).